# Bootstrap 3 Carousel Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

My carousel from Bootstrap won't display my images or react to the controls.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Skates R Us</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                        Skates R Us
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="contact.html">Contact / About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="new.html">New Products</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="media.html">Media</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                <li data-target="carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/slide_1.png" alt="Slide 1">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/slide_2.png" alt="Slide 2">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/slide_3.png" alt="Slide 3">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#carousel").carousel();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
#carousel {

    margin-top: 50px;

}

.carousel {
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
    z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-caption p {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            font-size: 21px;
            line-height: 1.4;
    }
}

img {
    background: red;
}
```

There are no errors in the Chrome console and the code is pretty much the exact same as that from the Bootstrap examples.

This is what the site looks like on my end:
[image: Site]

Comment: Could be because you don't have the jQuery document ready code in place: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using? 2.3.2 or 3.0?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3.0

Comment: And where did you get the css from?

Comment: The example on the Bootstrap site. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Comment: I couldn't debug the code, but if you only copied from the example, this might be helpful http://bootply.com/101080

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are just two minor things here.

The first is in the following carousel indicator list items:

```html
<li data-target="carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
```

You need to pass the `data-target` attribute a **selector** which means the ID must be prefixed with `#`.  So change them to the following:

```html
<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
```

Secondly, you need to give the carousel a starting point so both the carousel indicator items and the carousel inner items must have one `active` class.  Like this:

```html
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <!-- Other Items -->
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1500/600?image=1" alt="Slide 1" />
    </div>
    <!-- Other Items -->
</div>
```

## [Working Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XNr3z/)

Comment: @user2133268, when asking questions you really ought to try to do as much work as possible to make it a **good** question.  There is a *ton* of code here that has nothing to do with your example.  You should typically try to put your code into jsfiddle.net or bootply.com so other people can debug it immediately.  You should start with a working example from the docs and compare line by line to see where it's different.  Those are all ways that *you* can be at the helm of answering your own question.  They *empower* you.  It's good etiquette, but it makes you better at programming as well.

Comment: **SO** specifically enforce to post code in post if you have to post jsfiddle link !! @KyleMit

Answer (score 2):

Here is the changes you need to be done

just replace the carousel div with the below code

You have missed the '#' for data-target and add active class for the first item

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/slide_1.png" alt="Slide 1">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/slide_2.png" alt="Slide 2">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/slide_3.png" alt="Slide 3">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, Bootstrap Carousel has various parameters to control.

i.e.

**Interval:** Specifies the delay (in milliseconds) between each slide.

**pause:** Pauses the carousel from going through the next slide when the mouse pointer enters the carousel, and resumes the sliding when the mouse pointer leaves the carousel.

**wrap:** Specifies whether the carousel should go through all slides continuously, or stop at the last slide

For your reference:

[image]

Fore more details please [click here...](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp)

Hope this will help you :)

**Note:** This is for the further help.. I mean how can you customise or change default behaviour once carousel is loaded.

Comment: this was for the further help.. I mean how can you customise or change default behaviour once carousel is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I was helping a friend to find why their carousel was not working.  Controls would not work and images were not transitioning. I had a working sample on a page I had used and we went through all the code including checking the items above in this post. We pasted the "good" carousel into the same page and it still worked.  Now, all css and bootstrap files were the same for both. The code was now identical, so all we could try was the images.

So, we replaced the images with two that were working in my sample. It worked. We replaced the two images with the first two that were originally not working, and it worked.  We added back each image (all jpegs) one-by-one, and when we got to the seventh image (of 18) and the carousel failed.  Weird. We removed this one image and continued to add the remaining images until they were all added and the carousel worked.

for reference, we were using jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js and bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js on this site.

I do not know why an image would or could cause a carousel to malfunction, but it did. I couldn't find a reference to this cause elsewhere either, so I'm posting here for posterity in the hope that it might help someone else when other solutions fail.

**Test carousel with limited set of "known-to-be-good" images.**

Comment: In my case, after reading your answer, I found the CSS files were ok, but the one javascript file was missing. Included Bootstrap's `bootstrap.min.js` file and it worked. Thanks. Leaving a comment since it may be helpful for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the carousel wasn't working in the DreamWeaver CC provided the code in the "template" page I am playing with. I needed to add the data-ride="carousel" attribute to the carousel div in order for it to start working. Thanks to Adarsh for his code snippet which highlighted the missing attribute.